# Gene ratio as imput in limma

Tags: differential-expression, edger, limma

I have a data frame with gene-expression ratio. Is it possible to input this into limma/voom to find signinficannt gene-ratios between groups of samples?

my data:

```
                                   S1         S2         S3         S4         S5
hsa-let-7a-5p_hsa-let-7b-3p 80.066116 197.808511 275.322581 220.421053 242.100000
hsa-let-7a-5p_hsa-let-7b-5p  2.083889   2.393050   2.337716   1.062944   1.704930
hsa-let-7a-5p_hsa-let-7c-5p 83.517241  57.388889  85.350000  40.660194  71.205882
hsa-let-7a-5p_hsa-let-7d-3p  4.199393   5.792523   4.569058   3.193290   6.022388
hsa-let-7a-5p_hsa-let-7d-5p 32.729730  17.027473  14.490662   9.507378  22.416667
```

Comment: What do these ratio mean? Between what are those ratios calculated? But I'm not aware of any method that used ratios to calculate differentially expressed genes, as this is like a ratio